# SQLContext in Spark2 not getting updated hive table records

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a running application which queries hive table using HiveContext and it works fine if i run the application using  spark-submit in spark1.6 . As part of upgrade we switched to spark2.1  and using spark2-submit. Since spark2 doesnt support HiveContext  i m uing SQLContext instead. Issue i m facing is once i start the context any incremental changes in hive table is not visible in the hive query results. I am starting SparkContext with the enableHiveSupport() . IF i stop and restart the application i can see the rows. The application writing the data is doing MSCK REPAIR TABLE after writing so i am not sure what i am missing.

This is the code snippet

```
val spark= SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val sqlc=spark.sqlContext
sqlc.sql("select * from table1").show(false)

+---+----------+----+
| id|   hire_dt|user|
+---+----------+----+
|1.0|2018-01-01|John|
|2.0|2018-12-01|Adam|
+---+----------+----+
```

Now in another session i added new row but if i ran the above code it still returns only 2 rows .

This works fine if i do a refresh table ie

```
val spark= SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val sqlc=spark.sqlContext
sqlc.sql("refresh table table1")
sqlc.sql("select * from table1").show(false)
```

My question is why should i do a refeshTable since i never did to do it in spark1.6 when i query using HiveContext and SQLContext is supposed to behave the same way as HiveContext

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `sqlContext.refreshTable("my_table")`

in spark 2.x `spark.catalog.refreshTable("my_table")`

in SQL Format `spark.sql("refresh table my_table")`

Comment: Thanks but I hv 40 tBles refreshing each Before queries is an overhead. Why is this needed where in hivecontext it worked without it